# Renderer to Handler conversion in .Net MAUI

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I am converting Renderer into Handler for Grid in MAUI.
Following is the Custom control and its renderer. It is the normal Grid control as a header into the custom ListView with some columns.

```
    namespace Test.Helpers.DataGrid.Helpers
{
   public class DataGridGrid: Grid
   {
       public Action<bool>? OnResizeToggled;

        public Action<float>? OnResizeCommit { get; set; }
        public Action<float, bool>? OnResizing { get; set; }
        public Action OnSorting { get; set; }
        public int GridIndex { get; set; }
    }
}




     [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DataGridGrid), typeof(DataGridGridRenderer))]
    
    namespace Test.Droid.Helpers
    {
        public class DataGridGridRenderer : ViewRenderer<DataGridGrid, View>
        {
            private bool _resizing;
            private float _initialX;
            private bool _handlerAttached;
            private DataGridGrid _prev;
    
            public DataGridGridRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
            {
            }
    
            public float ConvertPixelsToDp(float px)
            {
                var density = Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
                return px / density;
            }
    
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DataGridGrid> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
    
                if (e.NewElement == null) return;
    
                if (_handlerAttached) return;
                _handlerAttached = true;
                Touch += HandleTouches;
            }
    
            private void HandleTouches(object sender, TouchEventArgs args)
            {
            }
                    
            }
}
```

Below is the Handler code in MAUI

```
    namespace Test.Platforms.Android.Handlers
{
    public partial class DataGridGridHandler : ViewHandler<DataGridGrid, View>
    {
        private bool _resizing;
        private float _initialX;
        private bool _handlerAttached;
        private DataGridGrid _prev;

        public DataGridGridHandler() : base(DGListViewMapper) { }
        public DataGridGridHandler(IPropertyMapper mapper, CommandMapper? commandMapper = null) : base(mapper, commandMapper) { }

        public static PropertyMapper<DataGridGrid, DataGridGridHandler> DGListViewMapper = new(ViewHandler.ViewMapper)
        {

        };
        public float ConvertPixelsToDp(float px)
        {
            var density = Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
            return px / density;
        }

        protected override View CreatePlatformView()
        {
              return new View(Context);//Returns blank 
        }
}
}
```

Adding handler as below in MAUIProgram.cs

```
    handlers.AddHandler(typeof(DataGridGrid), typeof(DataGridGridHandler));
```

The above handler returns a blank output. It should show a proper grid header with the column name. I know because of instantiating a new View but I wanted to know how I can just attach the event and copy the original Virtual view?
Please help

Comment: Does your original Renderer return a `PlatformView`?

Comment: @FreakyAli No. Even if I reuse the existing renderer it returns blank screen.

Comment: Did the custom handler's method excute? And did you try to use the [custom renderer in the maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers?view=net-maui-8.0)?

Comment: unfortunately, it is not working. I had to use the existing code as PlatformEffect and it served my purpose. There are very less materials available for complex custom controls for Listview, Grid etc.

Comment: I have tested the grid and use grid.handler to check the Grid's handler's type. But the handler is null. And glad to know you have used platformeffect to resolve it.